# Editing order email?

Tags: email, email-templates

I created a new product attribute and I want to display it in order email. How can I do that? 
I found the code in here:

```
app/design/frontend/base/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml
```

I try to add this line but it didn't work

```
<th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->__('my_attribute_code') ?></th>
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, may be its a typo(u missed default), the base path of the specified template file shhould be:
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml

Also, make sure the active theme on your website is not overriding this i.e check the following path if file exists:

app/design/frontend/YOURPACKAGE/YOURTHEME/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml

Cross Check your email template as well.